# what exactly the .parentNode is?

Tags: javascript, dom

I write a simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div>Hi</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this simple script on google chrome:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.parentNode.innerHTML);
console.log("%O",div);
```

then the console print out the innerHTML and the object.

expending the object then find out the value of parentNode is null.

I know the parentNode is one of the properties of node object, but what inside this variable?

it's a pointer? sub-object? function?

if it's a sub-object, would it be wasting memory to storage an object inside another object as the member variable?

Comment: the `parentNode` will be a reference to the parent of node, if it has one; otherwise it will be null. As per your example its pointing to `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have "pointers", or "sub-objects".  Every "object" variable (or property) is invisibly treated as a *reference* to an object.

```
var a = 1;    // a contains the value "1"
var b = {};   // b contains a reference to the newly created empty object {}
```

In this case, the `.parentNode` property is merely a reference to the `HTMLBodyElement` object that contains the `<div>`.

***More information:***

These references are somewhat like C's pointers, but they are completely *opaque* - you cannot obtain any meaningful *value* of a reference.  You may however *compare* references using the `===` operator to see if two references actually refer to the same object.

Every object is *reference counted* - if there are no more references (i.e. there are no in-scope variables or properties pointing at it) then the object may be *garbage collected*.

When you pass an object to a function you are actually passing a *copy of a reference*.  This means that within the function you may access that object's properties, and modify that object, but you cannot modify the caller's reference to the object.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no concept of "a pointer" or "a sub-object".

The value of `parentNode` is the object representing the DOM node that is the parent of the object on which the property is set (if it has one, if it doesn't, then it becomes `null` instead).

Like all values which are objects in JS, this is handled as a reference.